# jenkins choosing different provisioning profile specifier than terminal

Tags: xcode, bash, jenkins, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I have a Jenkins build a machine which is running a Jenkins job through a web hook integration with GitHub. When I run the command run by Jenkins by hand in the terminal I get it choosing the correct provisioning profile I specified but when I run it in Jenkins it reverts to the wrong provisioning profile...
I checked the env variables in Jenkins by doing sh 'env' but Jenkins does not seem to override the provisioning_profile_specifier anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by verifying that the command line was done using release instead of debug configuration. Jenkins uses command line configurations instead of the defaults set by Xcode.